# How to get the latest dnsmasq version?

Tags: networking, updates, security, dns, dnsmasq

I'd like to update to the latest version of dnsmasq (2.83). I used `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` in an attempt to update the software and libraries installed on the machine. I then checked my dnsmasq version with `dnsmasq -v` however the version is 2.80.

How can I get the latest version? I looked on the dnsmasq website and downloaded what seemed to be the latest release but I can't find the actual dnsmasq binary in the download.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an unusually specific request for such buried-under-the-hood software. What experience or problem leads you to believe that dnsmasq 2.83 is the solution?

Comment: I was initially looking to update to the latest version due to the recently discovered dnsmasq vulnerabilities, although it's been pointed out that a patch has been applied to the Ubuntu apt package. But if the dnsmasq package isn't kept up-to-date, what other packages contain outdated releases?

Comment: Whoa, back up there. Don't make that assumption. Please provide CVE number(s) for the vulnerability(ies) that you are asking about, and we can walk you through exactly how each is mitigated. "Recently discovered" is much too vague; we need the CVE number.

Comment: Apologies. The recently discovered vulnerabilities I meant are a collection of CVEs under the alias "[DNSpooq](https://www.jsof-tech.com/disclosures/dnspooq/)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's lead you through a single CVE, and you can do the rest yourself.

Prerequisite: You didn't say your release of Ubuntu, but we'll assume that it's Ubuntu 20.04 because only 20.04 uses dnsmasq 2.80.

1. **The list of CVEs** you provided is

   - CVE-2020-25681
   - CVE-2020-25682
   - CVE-2020-25683
   - CVE-2020-25687
2. **Plug one CVE** ("CVE-2020-25687") **into https://ubuntu.com/security/cve**

   - Alternately, you can try https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2020-25687
3. **Get the result**

[image]

- Note the Publish date (Not pictured: 19 January 2021)
- Note the Priority (Not pictured: Medium). Higher priority CVEs are patched faster. Low-priority CVEs are sometimes not patched, or are irrelevent
- And the result: CVE-2020-25687 was patched for 20.04 in the dnsmasq package version 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2.

4. **As a check**, let's look at the [changelog for the dnsmasq package](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/d/dnsmasq/dnsmasq_2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2/changelog)

```
   dnsmasq (2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2) focal-security; urgency=medium

     * SECURITY UPDATE: Multiple security issues
       - CVE-2020-25681: heap overflow in RRSets sorting
       - CVE-2020-25682: buffer overflow in extracting names from DNS packets
       - CVE-2020-25683: heap overflow in DNSSEC validation
       - CVE-2020-25684: cache poisoning issue via address/port
       - CVE-2020-25685: cache poisoning issue via weak hash
       - CVE-2020-25686: birthday attack via incorrect existing requests check
       - CVE-2020-25687: heap overflow in DNSSEC validation
       - CVE-2019-14834: memory leak via DHCP response creation

    -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 08 Jan 2021 09:59:59 -0500
```

5. **Let's find out** if we're running the patched version.

   - You cannot use `dnsmasq -v`. Both patched and unpatched will correctly show version 2.80. Patching bumps the version only from 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.1 to 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2.

   So instead, let's ask dpkg or apt

```
   you@YourSystem:~$ dpkg -l | grep dnsmasq
   ii  dnsmasq                               2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2                     
   amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server

   you@YourSystem:~$ apt list dnsmasq-base
   Listing... Done
   dnsmasq/focal-security,now 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
```

Ubuntu's Unattended Upgrades feature automatically installs security upgrades, so that you are already, like me, already running the patched version *without telling your system to do anything*.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about security, then you should know that all recent security fixes are backported to package versions. Installation of manually compiled 2.83 is overkill and unnecessary.

So they have fixes already included - see [Changelog for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/d/dnsmasq/dnsmasq_2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2/changelog) and https://ubuntu.com/security/cve?package=dnsmasq for all versions.

Comment: Would a fork from the main dnsmasq code not risk fracturing the code base?

Comment: Usage of distro-prepared packages are usually better and safer. Fork (or really clone) will cause problems with futures updates.

Comment: Why might distro-prepared packages be better and safer as opposed to a binary straight from the source?

Answer (score 0):

Using apt gets you the latest "packaged" version - the version packaged by Ubuntu which may not always be the latest version.

I assume you have Ubuntu 20.04 as 2.80 is the latest packaged version there, but Ubuntu 20.10 comes with 2.82 You can search for packages [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Looking at the [Dnsmasq website](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) it says that the tarball includes the source only, there are no binary releases available. So you will have to build it yourself.

I am sure there are plenty of guides/resources available online covering that subject so I won't attempt to cover that here.

Comment: Link to USN would be useful too - https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4698-1 .

Comment: What would be the advantage of installing a packaged version as opposed to compiling the binary myself (aside from ease of updates)?